# Change CRLF to LF of all the files in repo

Tags: git, eol

My repo has lots of files with CRLF.
I want them to be changed to LF.

I tried to change in my working copy and commit them but the changes are ignored by git.
The files with only change eol can be staged but can't be committed, right?

I can change eol and add another change on the first commit then I revert the change except for eol before next commit.
But it's so dirty solution.

Why does git ignore the eol changes?
Any good workaround for this?

I know `core.eol` and `core.autocrlf` in config and `* text=auto` in .gitattributes but they don't help me.

Comment: Just to be clear, `git ls-files --eol` shows that the files in both the index and working tree contain `crlf` line endings?

Comment: Most of the files are shown as `i/lf    w/crlf  attr/text=auto` and I noticed that I've accidentally set `* text=auto in my .gitattributes` and it overwrote my `git config core.autocrlf false`.
So, I thought the files in my repo were CRLF but actually they're LF and only the files in my working directory are CRLF.
I changed to `* text eol=lf`, commited it, checked out it, and I finally got LF files as-is to my working directory.
Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You have to [refresh your repository after changing line endings](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings) after setting `core.autocrlf`. This can be done using

```
git add --renormalize .
git commit -m "Normalize all the line endings"
```

Comment: Thanks for --renormalize! Really useful for cleaning up in old repos with mixed line endings among the commited files.